# Find surjective, continuous function such that diagram commutes

Tags: analysis

If we have a continuous function $g\colon X\to X$ with $g(Y)\subset Y$ and $h\colon Y\to Y$, where $h$ is the restriction of $g$ to $Y\subset X$, is there a continuous, surjective function $\pi\colon X\to Y$ such that
$$
\pi\circ g = h\circ\pi?
$$

Comment: Do You assume $g(Y)\subset  Y$?, since You write $h:Y\rightarrow Y$

Comment: Yes, I assume this.

Comment: One interesting special case to look at is when $g$ is the identity map. Even that's not trivial.

Comment: @Corona21 I suggest to include this assumption in the question.

Comment: Ok, I've done that.

Comment: @Arthur its not even trivial if $g$ is constant.

Comment: @Arthur this is an interesting question, and i am leaning towards the side that there is a counter example

Comment: I also have the feeling that there is a counter-example...

Comment: Oh, are we just looking for a single counterexample? That shouldn't be difficult. I thought we wanted to classify when it worked and when it didn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not always. Take $X=\mathbb{R}$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$. Take $g:X\to X$ as $g(x)=0$. Then $h:Y\to Y$ is given by $h(y)=0$. Note that $g$ is constant, so it is continuous and $g(Y)\subseteq Y$.

Any continuous function $\pi:X\to Y$ must be constant, so it cannot be surjective, and any surjective function $\pi:X\to Y$ cannot be continuous.